Is it possible to lift a map between pillow case orbifolds to a map between the planes that cover them?
I have an orbifold that is a pillow case: it is a quotient of $R^2$ by a group $G$ generated by $180^\circ$ rotations around a set of discrete points (that form a parallolgram grid).  I have a map from this orbifold to itself: $f: R^2/G \to R^2/G$. I'm pretty sure I can lift this map to a map $\tilde f: R^2 \to R^2$ to make a commuting diagram (i.e. $q \circ \tilde f = f \circ q$, where $q: R^2 \to R^2/G$ is the quotient map). But I'm not sure how to prove this, or better yet, where to find a reference for it. If these were regular covering spaces instead of orbifold covering spaces, i.e. if $G$ acted freely, it would be standard covering space stuff. (Note that the actual question I need to answer is for a map from a pillow case to itself, even though the title question is a bit more general.)

What properties does this map have? For instance, does it send the set of singular points to itself?

@MoisheKohan Yes it does send singular points to singular points. Also it is a homeomorphism.

It might be possible to prove this by leaning heavily on "regular" covering space theory and thinking about the "regular" covering space we get by removing the singular points of the orbifold downstairs and their preimages upstairs.

Yes, exactly...

@MoisheKohan do you know a reference for this?
